# Where to ask a question related to buying a new computer?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm considering buying a model of Dell computer that is so new that there are no reviews of it yet. So I want to ask if anyone has seen it and had any experience using it before I buy it.

I also need to ask for advice about whether I should accept a computer with a 5400 RPM drive or should go for one with 7200 RPM drive.

Where is the right place to post these questions and get some good answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among all the Stack Exchange sites, [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is the one that closely matches with the site that you are looking for.

Make sure to go through the help topic, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting the question. This will help you in framing a query which is on-topic for the site.

Answer (score 4):

On the whole - if you're asking about whether a higher RPM drive is better, or what the benefits are for a use case, Super User might work.

You don't want to focus on the *models* - you probably want to talk about your use case (laptop or desktop) and ask about the advantages (power use? Performance?) and disadvantages of either rotational speed.

That said, you're *best off* doing a few quick searches on Super User first- Searching for [5400rpm](https://superuser.com/search?q=5400%20rpm) yielded a few interesting existing posts for example, and this is something that's probably reasonably commonly asked. Your answer is probably *already there*.

Comment: I took this suggestion and put the question about the hard drive on SuperUser: (https://superuser.com/questions/1449347/is-a-5400-rpm-drive-suitable-in-a-dual-drive-system). But it was almost immediately put on hold there as asking for an opinion. So I reposted it on Hardware Recommendations: (https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/is-a-5400-rpm-drive-suitable-in-a-dual-drive-system).